# QProgressBar update in QThread quitting crashes

Tags: qt, qthread, qprogressbar

I have the following code that works as expected.  It updates the progress bar value in each for loop.  The only issue I have is when I'm done and call emit ProcessUserRowsFinished() in the method OnProcessUserRowsStarted the program crashes.

```
class UsersProcess: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    UsersProcess(CTCore::DBConnect* db_context, UserSettingsMap user_settings_map);
    void SetProgressBar(QProgressBar *progress_bar);

private:

    QProgressBar *progressBar;
    QSharedPointer<QList<CTCoreZen::User>> listUsers;
    QScopedPointer<QThread> threadRowWorker;

signals:
    void ProcessUserRowsFinished();
    void ProgressBarSetValue(int value);

}   

void UsersProcess::SetProgressBar(QProgressBar *progress_bar)
{
    this->progressBar = progress_bar;
}

void UsersProcess::OnUserListSuccess(QList<CTCoreZen::User> *users)
{
    this->listUsers.reset(users);

    this->progressBar->setVisible(true);
    this->progressBar->setTextVisible(true);
    this->progressBar->setMinimum(0);
    this->progressBar->setMaximum(this->listUsers->size());
    this->progressBar->setValue(0);



    this->threadRowWorker.reset(new QThread());
    this->moveToThread(this->threadRowWorker.data());

    connect(this->threadRowWorker.data(), &QThread::started, this, &UsersProcess::OnProcessUserRowsStarted);

    connect(this, &UsersProcess::ProgressBarSetValue, this->progressBar, &QProgressBar::setValue);

    connect(this, &UsersProcess::ProcessUserRowsFinished, this->threadRowWorker.data(), &QThread::quit);
    connect(this, &UsersProcess::ProcessUserRowsFinished, this, &UsersProcess::deleteLater);
    connect(this->threadRowWorker.data(), &QThread::finished, this->threadRowWorker.data(), &QThread::deleteLater);

    this->threadRowWorker->start();
}   

void UsersProcess::OnProcessUserRowsStarted()
{
    int row = 0;

    UsersData userData(this->dbContext);

    int maxRows = this->listUsers->size();
    for(auto iter = this->listUsers->begin(); iter != this->listUsers->end(); ++iter)
    {
         row++;
         emit this->ProgressBarSetValue(row);
    }

    emit ProcessUserRowsFinished();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of your thread has been deleted.
This call deletes the instance of class UsersProcess and QScopedPointer deletes the thread.

```
connect(this, &UsersProcess::ProcessUserRowsFinished, this, &UsersProcess::deleteLater);
```

But you also have this connections

```
connect(this, &UsersProcess::ProcessUserRowsFinished, this->threadRowWorker.data(), &QThread::quit);
connect(this->threadRowWorker.data(), &QThread::finished, this->threadRowWorker.data(), &QThread::deleteLater);
```

When one of this events fires the thread is already deleted.

Comment: I'm following the example in this link: https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/  So is this done incorrectly?  What is the best way to do this? Or is it because I'm using a QSharedPointer?

Comment: Yes, you can just remove scoped pointer or remove this two connections.

Comment: I finally tested and it worked thank you for the information